# IP Address in a MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, maskedtextbox

How can I use a MaskedTextBox to prevent the user from entering an invalid IP address? (I want it to behave just like the Windows one).

Comment: Why not just read the value in and save the user some trouble?  Never make a user do what you can do for them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
IPAddress ipAddress;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(maskedTextBoxY.Text, out ipAddress))
{
    //valid ip
 }
else
 {
    //is not valid ip
}
```

note: to use it, you need import the `System.Net` namespace:

```
using System.Net;
```

Answer (score 24):

Much simpler than the other answers:

Use System.Net.IPAddress and System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox

set the following properties of the MaskedTextBox:

```
MaskedTextBox.Mask = ###.###.###.###
MaskedTextBox.ValidatingType = typeof(System.Net.IPAddress);
```

whenever the text box is validating, event MaskedTextBox.TypeValidationCompleted is raised.
The event arguments show the following:

- Is the typed text acceptable as an IP address? (= does System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse return ok)
- Description of the error as a string
- The parsed value (= an object of System.NET.IpAddress
- The type of the parsed value. Needed if you have several MaskedTextBoxes with different masks

Upon receipt of this event you can decide whether to use the value or notify the user what is wrong with the value.

Comment: Does NOT work.Only works for 123.123.123.123 - ie ALL characters present. IP address of  "123.4.5.6" will appear as "123.456.."

Comment: Subscribe to event KeyDown and react the way you want to be the input if the operator presses a dot / semicolon / comma / right arrow / tab etc.

Comment: Also the . should probably be an escaped literal...  "\."

Comment: cb88: if you type it as a string, it should be escaped. However, in the visual studio designer properties you don't escape these characters, the input is as text in a text box, the software will escape it for you

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use REGEX to validate user input. Here's an example:

```
         string pattern = @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b";

        string ip1 = "192.168.0.1";
        string ip2 = "302.0.0.1";

        Regex.IsMatch(ip1, pattern); // returns true
        Regex.IsMatch(ip2, pattern); // returns false
```

Comment: Um, since when? This doesn't answer the question at all. -1

Comment: @minitech - I believe Woot4Moo is referring to that old saw about regexes - see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: @WillChesterfield: I was referring to Dan's post, not Woot4Moo's comment. `System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse` is far better.

Answer (score 2):

Set the mask to: `###.###.###.###`

Will display like this:

[image]

Comment: @Woot4Moo I don't think can be done with a single mask. You'll need to listen for key pressed and handle wich characters are/aren't allowed

Comment: Correct, MaskedTextBox does not allow you to do complex validations directly. You can use KeyPress event to read user input and determine in it is valid. And a right Regex expression does help to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complex solution for this question yet. I think @HaraldDutch answer is closest, but it is not prevet from input with space character.
Using additional instruction:

```
IPAdressBox.ResetOnSpace = false;
```

generaly solved problem, but more complex is to implement own custom data typewith Parse method.

```
            public class IPValidator
            {
                public static IPValidator Parse(string input)
                {
                    Regex regexpr = new Regex(@" ");
                    Match match = regexpr.Match(input);
                    if (match.Success)
                        return new IPValidator();
                    else throw new ArgumentException(input);
                }
            }
```

Where regexpr is specific expresion to validate IP. After that it can be use as ValidatingType:

```
 IPAdressBox.ValidatingType = typeof(IPValidator);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an IP masked textbox that mimicks the Windows one.

Has the same width, height, prevents users from entering >255 values, jumps boxes, etc, etc...
If you still need it and want to try it out it's here:

https://github.com/RuvenSalamon/IP-MaskedTextBox

(I don't know if this counts as self promotion but it's open-source so I reckon it's ok.)