# Use maskedtextctrl for IP address in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mask

ALL,
I have a very simple WinForms application with C#.NET.
In there I need the control for entering an IP address, so I used MaskedTextCtrl.
This control needs to have a default value of localhost, i.e. the value should be there when the program starts, so I use "Text" property of the control.

I set the mask to be "999.999.999.999" and the text to "127.0.0.1", which converts to "127001" and it displays incorrectly in the GUI designer and when the program starts.

What can I do to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: localhost is not an IP address, it's a string. A single control will probably not disagree both DNS names *and* IP addresses. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @CodyGray, looking for "127.0.0.1".

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP Address in a MaskedTextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox) - the MaskTextCtrl cant do it without an ugly user experience, the duplicate has your best options IMO

Comment: @JeremyThompson, This is not a duplicate. It's talking about user entering IP address. What I'm talking is have an IP address pre-populated and displayed. In fact I think "MaskedTextBox" is not suitable for that. Can you prove otherwise? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the text control with the Validation.

Answer (score 0):

I heed your comments:

> This is not a duplicate. It's talking about user entering IP address.
>   What I'm talking is have an IP address pre-populated and displayed. In
>   fact I think "MaskedTextBox" is not suitable for that. Can you prove
>   otherwise?

But the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox) is asking the same thing with code and also UI.

[image]

*Edit: I did search for a control before I posted a comment and Telerik seem to have something [along these lines](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Telerik+masked+textbox+ipaddress&sugexp=chrome,mod=12&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I also saw some problems with it too*

Comment: We probably talk about 2 different things. Here is what I see when I click on the "duplicate" link: "How can I use a MaskedTextBox to prevent the user from entering an invalid IP address? (I want it to behave just like the Windows one". This question is about user input. Did you make a mistake when referencing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we are talking about the same control. Do not try and bend the spoon. That's impossible. Instead... only try to realize the truth. I have shown you the `windows one` and that this a chameleon question.