# Unable to compare int? to null

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Look at this code which I surrounded by textchanged event of a text box:

```
        string testString = comboIPAddress.Text;
        string[] parts = testString.Split('.');
        int? ipclass = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        if (ipclass == null)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        if (ipclass >= 1 && ipclass <= 126)
        {
            comboSubnet.Text = "255.0.0.0";
        }
        if (ipclass >= 192 && ipclass <= 223)
        {
            comboSubnet.Text = "255.255.255.0";
        }
        if (ipclass >= 128 && ipclass <= 191)
        {
            comboSubnet.Text = "255.255.0.0";
        }
        else
        {
            comboSubnet.Text = "";
        }
```

While executing the exe if I delete everything from IPAddress combo box, it is giving error(Input string was not in a correct format.). I don't know the other way to compare an int to null. Please help.

Comment: What are the contents of `parts` if `testString` is empty?

Comment: You should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non-nullable `int` and check if parsable with [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)...

```
int ipclass;
if (!int.TryParse(parts[0], out ipclass))
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: It only needed copy and paste. Thanks Man

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a MaskedTextBox for the IP? You can then parse the input easily using the [System.Net.IPAddress Parse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx)
as shown in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox).

Answer (score 0):

You should test `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testString))` before trying to split it, followed by `int.TryParse`