# C# WinForm Check special words with TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to check user input values in textBox,like this [127.0.0.1]、[255.255.255.128].

The input value is between 1~255, but now have a problem when typing ".", the numbers & dot it's required.

I try to use if condition when input dot, but if continue input dot will go wrong.
How should I do?

```
private void Check_Number(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int intNumber = 0;
            TextBox tempBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (tempBox.Text != "")
            {
                if (tempBox.Text == ".") return;
                intNumber = int.Parse(tempBox.Text);
                if (intNumber >= 1 && intNumber <= 255)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Over the Upper Limit", "Error");
                    tempBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you are want to parse the input to an IP address. Remember that they can contain zero-digits, like in your example 127.0.0.1

Comment: Note that you could use several `NumericUpDown` controls to limit some input errors.

Comment: Or a maskedtextbox

Comment: [IPTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781845/14171304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `tempBox.Text` by `.` as a delimitor and then you can compare each value is within a range or not,

```
var isValidIPAddress = tempBox.Text.Split('.')  //Split by '.'
          .Select(Int32.Parse) //Convert it to integer
          .All(intNumber => intNumber >= 1 && intNumber <= 255); //Check each int number is within given range

if(isValidIPAddress)
    Console.WriteLine($"{tempBox.Text} is Valid IP address");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"{tempBox.Text} is Not a Valid IP address");
```

Try Online: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahA8uJ)

Comment: Thank offer your method, and this method is close to what I need.

Comment: And var isValidIPAddress is boolean?
I can't use it in Visual C# winform.

Comment: yes `isValidIPAddress` is boolean, You can use it in C# winform. Any reason for `I can't use it in Visual C# winform.` this statement?

Comment: First, Split(".") can't from 'string' to 'char',
Second, All(intNumber =>),  this intNumber can't declare do local variable or parameter, because this name has been used local variable range

Comment: `Split(".") can't from 'string' to 'char'` can you please tell me more on it. Regarding  `All(intNumber =>)` Now you need not to define `int intNumber = 0;` at top level.

Comment: I change Split(".") to Split('.') , and can work

Comment: I updated my answer too. Thanks for fixing issue from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use IPAddress Method as following:

```
IPAddress IP;
var isIPAddress = IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1",out IP);

if(isIPAddress)
{
    //your logic
}
else
{
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: Thank offer your method.  This provides me with another idea :)

Comment: This is the best answer. You should have got the acceptance.

Comment: @Enigmativity its ok bro still may help someone need it ❤️

Comment: I agree with @Enigmativity too. Your solution is elegant than me